# Parsing out text from webpage

Tags: python, selenium

I am attempting to parse out the text from the below xpath using Selenium. I am getting the below traceback error

```py
date = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//[@id="General"]/fieldset/dl/dd[5]/text()').text()
print(date)
```

traceback:

```
InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector: The result of the xpath expression "//*[@id="General"]/fieldset/dl/dd[5]/text()" is: [object Text]. It should be an element.
```

I believe that Selenium doesn't allow you to parse out the text nodes (my end goal) what library should I use here?

Comment: what inside response?

Comment: what is `driver`? Scrapy doesn't have `driver`. Maybe you mean module `Selenium` which often uses name `driver`. But then you get HTML with `driver.page_source` and you have to use `BeautifulSoup`. In `Scrapy` you get `response` in `def parse(response):` and you use it drectly without any `current_url`

Comment: your code makes no sense. It looks like you mix code from different modules - `scrapy`  and `Selenium`. You should edit question or it should be closed.

Comment: @furas - Apologies, I had haphazardly pasted code that wasn't complete at all. I made the changes to the post. I am using selenium now but its come to my attention that this portion of the script cannot be done using selenium, as i am trying  to pull a text field and it doesn't allow for that to be done.

Comment: last `.text` is not function but variable so remove `()` and remove `/text()` from `xpath`

Comment: This is honestly just a mess. Are you still having any problems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `.text` is an *attribute* not method so remove `()`
- remove `/text()` from `xpath` because `Selenium` can't return text (or attribute like `@href`) and you have to use `.text` for this (and `.get_attribute('href')` for attribute).

---

```
date = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//[@id="General"]/fieldset/dl/dd[5]').text
print(date)
```

Comment: I have replaced the word _variable_ with _attribute_. Let me know if it's okay with you.

Comment: @DebanjanB you are right. It sound better.  Maybe I should also replace `function` with `method`

Comment: That would sound more canonical.

Comment: @DebanjanB so I changed it

Comment: Thank you so much! Works great now!